# Django Tastypie User Objects Only Authorization

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I want to use Tastypie authorization to give users access to only their objects. However, I am having problems understanding if I am doing it correctly. I followed the example here:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#implementing-your-own-authorization

When I try to create a new object, I get a 404 error because there are problems evaluating

```
def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    return bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user
```

Everything works if I comment that out. I thought commenting those two lines out would allow the user to create objects for other users, but when I tried it, I correctly get a 401 (UNAUTHORIZED) response.

Does that mean those two lines are unnecessary? How is Tastypie able to correctly determine if I am authorized to create objects?

When I was running this, I sent a POST request with 'user' equal to the appropriate URI (something like '/api/v1/user/1/'). I'm not sure if Tastypie is having problems determining

```
bundle.obj.user
```

when I do it that way.

Is it safe to just leave those two lines commented out? Is Tastypie authorizing the user with one of the other methods?

Comment: `bundle.obj.user == bundle.request.user` will return true if you are changing a row that your user owns (row level authorization). Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. That works correctly when I do a PUT request. However, it doesn't work during a POST request. POST only works if I remove those two lines.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. I would report it as an issue on Tastypie's Github page.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    return bundle.obj == bundle.request.user
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bundle.obj isn't populated during the create_detail authorization.

Also, create_detail for a user really doesn't make much sense, because there's no object for the user to own until its created anyways. You could just check if bundle.request.user is a valid user with permissions on the model.

In my case, I needed to check if the created object referenced an object owned by the user, so here's what I came up with:

```
def create_detail(self, object_list, bundle):
    resource=BookResource()
    book=resource.get_via_uri(bundle.data["book"], bundle.request)
    return book.user == bundle.request.user
```

Anyways, bottom line: tastypie's docs are a little off.

And, I hope this helps.